# Programatically set connection string with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 5.5.1

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I am upgrading nuget-packages for a webjob-project rocking the 4.3.0 version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, where the connection string can be set programmatically like this:

```
.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
{
   b.AddServiceBus(options =>
   {
      options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
   });
})
```

Which works great. We store the connection string in Azure Key Vault instead of in the appsettings-file.

However, after upgrading to 5.5.1, there is no option to set the connection string.

Is there any other way to set this? On the trigger itself, you can only specify the name of the setting in appsettings.json.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus_5.5.1/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Config/ServiceBusOptions.cs

Managed Identity can be used to avoid secrets in the settings-file but this specific project has not that configured in Azure yet for service bus and I would prefer to keep the current solution until we can move to use managed identity for all connections at once.

Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus

Documentation:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus_5.5.1/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/README.md

A solution I thought might work was to add Key Vault to the configuration (system assigned managed identity is used here):

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) =>
{
  var keyVaultUrl = "...";    
  config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
})
```

And then specify the secret name in the attribute:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, Connection = "secret-name")] string messageJson
```

But that only gives me an error that I think it related to it not accessing the service bus correctly.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Can't bind parameter 'messageReceiver' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver'
```

Comment: hi, how did you fix this?

Answer (score -2):

---

Storing Service Bus Connection string , you can use **Azure Key Vault Service** .

add this line of code in local.settings.json

```
"Connectionstring": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://connectionmt.vault.azure.net/secrets/AzureFunctionKeyVaultConnections/abcd46389abdeujewfuew898)"
```

local.settings.json code.

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://xxxservicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxx",
    "Connectionstring": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://connectionstring-mt.vault.azure.net/secrets/AzureFunctionKeyVaultConnections/xxx)"
  }
}
```

we create function , where we print connection string in console.

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {

            string connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Connectionstring");
            Console.WriteLine(connection);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

[image]

in this code we print connection string value, which come from azure key vault.